# Django class based views, no loader erro

Tags: python, django

While the code below works fine when the server is running, using south or syncdb gives me errors:

```
SomeTemplateView.as_view(template_name=get_template("app/test.html").name)
```

However this code works both during server running and using south or syncdb:

```
SomeTemplateView.as_view(template_name="app/test.html")
```

What's the catch?

Comment: The error is:django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing template source loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: "'module' object has no attribute 'Loader'"